# Cannot Generate RuleApp on IBM Decision Center

Tags: deployment, ilog, jrules

deploy rules written using RuleApp created from rule projects, on to the Sample Rule Execution Server[ RES ] from the Decision Center on Local Samples Server version 8.5 and I have the below error

Any Suggestions on this or ideas on how to resolve are greatly appreciated

[image: Error on Decision center while trying to Deploy RuleApp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it looks like the ruleset table is not updated in decision center db. Did you try deleting this baseline and creating afresh from scratch then try to create rule app.

Comment: Yes, it definitely looks like it. We have dynamic domains and running the generated SQL, from the configure tab after generation helped resolve the issue, since it is local we did not bother about the baseline creation as of now.